# AWS lambda hitting size limitation with ffmpeg

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I'm playing around with AWS lambda and trying to set up a task based on `node` + `ffmpeg`. Apparently Lambda cannot handle zip that are larger than 250Mb (I'm getting the exception `Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes`)

I've followed the build guideline [from ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and my final build is 377Mb:

[image]

There might be a few things I can prune, but I'm not sure I can get bellow 200+Mb. Is Lambda not fit for ffmpeg tasks? If people have used for video processing, is the only solution to drastically prune `ffmpeg` build?

== edit ==

As mentioned in @idbehold's answer, it's likely that I only need the binaries. I first tried with only the binaries in `./bin`, but I was getting errors like:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Command failed: /bin/sh -c ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams test.mp4
  ffprobe: error while loading shared libraries: libva.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "ffprobe: error while loading shared libraries: libva.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
    "",
    "ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)",
    "emitTwo (events.js:87:13)",
    "ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)","maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)",
    "Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)",
    "emitOne (events.js:77:13)",
    "Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)",
    "Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)"
  ]
}
```

The lambda is just executing an input command with a `child_process` as in the `node-exec` blueprint aws function. So I thought I'd need to include those other files. I copied the binaries I obtained after following ffmpeg installation guidelines, but maybe they got linked differently in my ubuntu machine. I guess I should focus on fixing that error.

Comment: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ this static build is just 16MB as tar.xz.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the binaries from the bin folder.

Comment: that's what I first thought, and then the issue I mentioned in my edit made me thing otherwise. I'll try again.